# How to read from a list of lists and add the details to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
ratings = [['item1', 0.95], ['item5', 0.99], ['item3', 0.3]]
```

I also have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
item price
item1  350
item2  678
item3  888
item4  386
item5 1000
item6  85
```

Now, I want to add the `ratings` details to the above dataframe and get a dataframe that only has ratings as follows.

```
item price  ratings
item1  350   0.95
item3  888   0.3
item5 1000   0.99
```

I feel like this can be done using `isin()`, but quite not sure how to use it with `lists of list`.

Finally, I want another dataframe that rank the items based on the rantings as below.

```
item price  ratings   rankings
item1  350   0.95        2
item3  888   0.3         3
item5 1000   0.99        1
```

Is there any easy way of doing this in pandas?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: after `merge` do `rank`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would turn the list to a df and merge:

```
ratings = [['item1', 0.95], ['item5', 0.99], ['item3', 0.3]]
df1=pd.DataFrame(ratings,columns=['item','ratings'])
df=df.merge(df1,on=['item'])
df['ranks']=df.ratings.rank(method='dense')
#df['ranks']=df.ratings.rank(method='dense',ascending=False) for reverse rank
print(df)
```

---

```
    item  price  ratings  ranks
0  item1    350     0.95    2.0
1  item3    888     0.30    1.0
2  item5   1000     0.99    3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `map`:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in ratings}
u = df.assign(ratings=df.item.map(d)).dropna()
```

```
    item  price  ratings
0  item1    350     0.95
2  item3    888     0.30
4  item5   1000     0.99
```

---

Then `rank`

```
u.assign(rankings=u.ratings.rank(ascending=False))
```

```
    item  price  ratings  rankings
0  item1    350     0.95       2.0
2  item3    888     0.30       3.0
4  item5   1000     0.99       1.0
```